# Changing data structure from list of objects to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json

I am learning and practicing data structures in python. I have a JSON data like below, it shows a part of it. I want to load this to bigquery locally. Of course I receive **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'**. I think this error happens because of my data structure is list.

```
 result =   [
                {
                    "model": "ford",
                    "color": "red",
                    "year": 1993
                },
                {
                    "model": "opel",
                    "color": "white",
                    "year": 2000
                }
            ]
```

Can I turn this to dictionary just adding one key name e.g

```
result = { "results":   [
                    {
                        "model": "ford",
                        "color": "red",
                        "year": 1993
                    },
                    {
                        "model": "opel",
                        "color": "white",
                        "year": 2000
                    }
                ]
          }
```

I thought If I change my data structure to this I can avoid the error but I was not able to find a way to change the structure. Or how can I load my data to BQ, if this is not the right way. Many thanks!

Comment: _I have a JSON data like below, it shows a part of it._ That doesn't look like JSON. _Of course I receive AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'._ What do you mean _of course_ ? It isn't obvious to me. Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I mean I receive this error because I have a list and I am aware of it. For that reason, I was trying to change my data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to change from list into a dict:

```
result = {'results': result}
```

Comment: I was trying sth like this result["results"] = result, okay this was easy. I don't know why I didn't see this. Thanks a lot, I will accept the answer when it is available.

Comment: The problem with this  result["results"] = result is really because the name of the list and the dict is the same and thus  result["results"] gives error since result is still a list.